# Insert files from folder (OPENROWSET(BULK...)) into table with details

Tags: database, file, t-sql, sql-server-2012, directory

I'm trying to copy multiple files from specific folder and subfolders into MS SQL 2012. I want to get file details and import them in database as well. I want to get following file details:

- Date Created
- Date Modified
- Size

This is the query that I have:

```
DECLARE  @sql nvarchar(max)
        , @filename nvarchar(256)
        , @filepath varchar(100)

DECLARE @FileList TABLE (filename nvarchar(256), depth int, fl int)

INSERT INTO @FileList
EXEC xp_dirtree @filepath, 10, 1;

DECLARE curDoc CURSOR FOR
SELECT filename FROM @FileList WHERE fl = 1

OPEN curDoc FETCH NEXT FROM curDoc INTO @filename

WHILE (@@FETCH_STATUS = 0)
  BEGIN
    SET @sql = 'INSERT INTO _table SELECT * FROM OPENROWSET(BULK ''' + @filepath + @filename + ''', SINGLE_BLOB) as tbl'

    PRINT @sql

    EXEC sp_executesql @sql

    FETCH NEXT FROM curDoc
    INTO @filename
  END

CLOSE curDoc

DEALLOCATE curDoc
```

Comment: Use `SSIS` instead. Cursor + undocumented xp_dirtree + dynamic sql -> may cause problems.

Comment: I am not familiar with SSIS.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141239.aspx and https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141134.aspx